# Geospatial fixed radius cluster hunting in python

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I want to take an input of millions of lat long points (with a numerical attribute) and then find all fixed radius geospatial clusters where the sum of the attribute within the circle is above a defined threshold.

I started by using sklearn BallTree to sum the attribute within any defined circle, with the intention of then expanding this out to run across a grid or lattice of circles. The run time for one circle is around 0.01s, so this is fine for small lattices, but won't scale if I want to run 200m radius circles across the whole of the UK.

```
#example data (use 2m rows from postcode centroid file)
df = pandas.read_csv('National_Statistics_Postcode_Lookup_Latest_Centroids.csv', usecols=[0,1], nrows=2000000)
#this will be our grid of points (or lattice) use points from same file for example
df2 = pandas.read_csv('National_Statistics_Postcode_Lookup_Latest_Centroids.csv', usecols=[0,1], nrows=2000)

#reorder lat long columns for balltree input
columnTitles=["Y","X"]
df = df.reindex(columns=columnTitles)
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=columnTitles)

# assign new columns to existing dataframe. attribute will hold the data we want to sum over (set to 1 for now)
df['attribute'] = 1
df2['aggregation'] = 0

RADIANT_TO_KM_CONSTANT = 6367
class BallTreeIndex:
    def __init__(self, lat_longs):
        self.lat_longs = np.radians(lat_longs)
        self.ball_tree_index =BallTree(self.lat_longs, metric='haversine')

    def query_radius(self,query,radius):
        radius_km = radius/1000
        radius_radiant = radius_km / RADIANT_TO_KM_CONSTANT
        query = np.radians(np.array([query]))
        indices = self.ball_tree_index.query_radius(query,r=radius_radiant)
        return indices[0]

#index the base data
a=BallTreeIndex(df.iloc[:,0:2])
#begin to loop over the lattice to test performance
for i in range(0,100):
    b = df2.iloc[i,0:2]
    output = a.query_radius(b, 200)
    accumulation = sum(df.iloc[output, 2])
    df2.iloc[i,2] = accumulation
```

It feels as if the above code is really inefficient as I don't need to run the calculation across all circles on my lattice (as most will be well below my threshold - or will have no data points in at all).

Instead of this for loop, is there a better way of scaling this algorithm to give me the most dense circles?

I'm new to python, so any help would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: Could you update the final version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

First don't try to do this on a sphere! GB is small and we have a well defined geographic projection that will work. So use the `oseast1m` and `osnorth1m` columns as X and Y. They are in metres so no need to convert (roughly) to degrees and use Haversine. That should help.

Next add a [spatial index](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/) to speed up lookups.

If you need more speed there are various tricks like loading a 2R strip across the country into memory and then running your circles across that strip, then moving down a grid step and updating that strip (checking Y values against a fixed value is quick, especially if you store the data sorted on Y then X value). If you need more speed then look at any of the [papers the Stan Openshaw](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Openshaw%20gam%20speedup) (and sometimes I) wrote about parallelising the GAM. There are examples of implementing GAM in python (e.g. [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270553825_Geo-visual_Approach_for_Spatial_Scan_Statistics_An_Analysis_of_Dengue_Fever_Outbreaks_in_Delhi), [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.0016-7363.2005.00672.x)) that may also point to better ways.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Ian. I think using Euclidean distance rather than Haversine is a good call and should save on some run time.The raw data that I will be using will have lat longs but no grid references, I also would like to extend this to work for countries outside of the UK if possible- which means using gridreferences instead of lat long may not be possible. I already use BallTree to spatially index my data points, are you suggesting also indexing my grid of points to run over? Can I do distance calcs between two spatially indexed data sets?

Comment: In other countries you should reproject to a projected coordinate reference system - most will have one or more local grids defined.